# Cucumber @javascript Breaks Oracle SQL Calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 Cucumber 1.0.1, and Oracle as the database. I have my own local user/schema for my development database, but I also connect to another Oracle database in a read-only fashion. Someone as my work has created a gem that allows me to talk to that other database and access its models. Let's say we call that other database Servo. Then I am able to do something like `Servo::ModelName.all` and all other regular calls.

The Oracle that gets generated by that is something like: `SELECT * FROM "SERVO"."MODELNAMES";` Note that it appends the SERVO database name.

Now, I am writing a Cucumber test that at times, in my custom steps, uses Servo. That all works fine. The new scenario I am writing uses the `@javascript` tag. If any step (in the Background or in the Scenario) does *not* use Servo, then it runs fine. However, if I *do* use Servo, it breaks. The Oracle SQL being generated is suddenly `SELECT * FROM "MODELNAMES";` and it is no longer aware of the other database.

So, any ideas why this is happening? Why does the `@javascript` suddenly change the SQL being generated? I couldn't find any good documentation about what else it does besides launching Firefox.

I'm sure others may want to know more information but I didn't want to flood this question so just let me know if you want some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference @javascript will introduce on the application side is that you're running a web server instead of routing requests directly through rack. I'd investigate with that knowledge and see if there isn't something you're doing in an initializer or something which could be affected by the different context.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I couldn't seem to find anything useful on how `@javascript` works. I haven't had any luck resolving my issue yet, but thanks for the information.

Comment: +1 for your time and help. It really did help us start investigating to the right solution. In the end it was something to do with cucumber actually, in the way that it deals with ActiveRecord. There should be a pull request going in for it soon. We've monkey patched it for now and have it working again. Thank you! (Also +rep because I am going to close it by just giving yours as the right answer. Cheers!)